# How to display a calendar in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, module, calendar, block

I'm trying to use the [calender block module](http://drupal.org/project/calendar_block) and basically display a calendar in my theme. So I have enabled the module in the admin interface, then in my theme file (page.tpl.php), I have typed the following:

```
$block = (object)module_invoke('calendar_block', 'block', 'view', '0');
print theme('block',$block);
```

However this only display "CALENDAR" in uppercase but no calendar shows up. When I look at the source there's only a div with class "calendar_ajax", which makes me think the rendering should be done by JavaScript, but it's not happening.

Does anybody know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as seems likely, the calender rendering happens via JavaScript, then the issue is probably that you create the block 'manually' from code in your template file, instead of the 'normal' way of adding it to a region via the block configuration page.

The module probably adds the needed JavaScript by means of a `drupal_add_js()` call, which adds JavaScript files or code to the variables passed into the page template for output inclusion. However, *this only works if `drupal_add_js()` is called before the execution/rendering of page.tpl.php*, as the JavaScript files and code are already assembled/aggregated for output at that time, so it is to late to add any more.

While there are ways to work around this problem inside page.tpl.php (or in a preprocess function), they are ugly and should be avoided if possible. Try to use the 'normal' way of adding blocks to regions (or check out the alternate module suggested by mikl).

---

EDIT: Concerning the 'normal' way, I'd suggest to take a look at the [Working with blocks (content in regions)](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/block) documentation, as it gives a good overview and has some useful links to more detailed information.

For a quick approach, check the `admin/build/block/list` configuration page of your Drupal instance. It should provide one page (tab) per enabled theme, listing the theme regions, along with the blocks placed in those regions.

At the bottom of those lists, you'll find the 'disabled' blocks, i.e. those that are not assigned to any region. I'd expect the calendar block to be listed there, and you could try to move it to one of your themes regions and see if it shows up then (or better yet, switch to the default Garland theme first, test the block there, and then switch back to your theme - that way, you can be sure if it works in principle, independent of your themes settings/configurations).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation of what's happening behind the scene is useful; however I still wonder what would be the "normal" way to add this block to my page? It seems there's so many ways to do things in Drupal that I never know what the normal way is supposed to be. So if I want to add this block to a page in my theme, is there any way to do it (without manually adding the drupal_add_js calls, etc.)?

Comment: @Laurent: I edited my answer to include some hints on the 'normal' way. (And yup, the 'many ways to achieve the same result' side of Drupal is both an advantage and a disadvantage at the same time. It gives quite some flexibility, but makes it harder to fully understand the system :/

Answer (score 2):

Try the [calendar module](http://drupal.org/project/calendar). This allows you to use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to set up calendars of all kinds of different content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$block = module_invoke('calendar_block', 'block', 'view', 0);
print $block['content'];
```